# How To Reference Pivot Table Results In A Mail Range Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I am Running the below code to automate the selection of AC numbers in a Pivot table. Which on its own works perfectly

```
Sub Pivotselection()

    Dim pi As PivotItem

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Account Number")

        For Each pi In .PivotItems

            .CurrentPage = pi.Name
            Call Mail_Range
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

The Trouble that I am having is that when I try to call the Mail_Range macro it comes up with a Complile Error: Type Mismatch

I have declared the Pivotal Item in the Mail_Range macro but it hasnt made any difference.

```
Sub Mail_Range()

    Dim Source As Range

    Dim Dest As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set Source = pi.Name
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Source = pi.Name
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Source Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The source is not a range or the sheet is protected, please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Dest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    Source.Copy
    With Dest.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Selection of " & wb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2016
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
    End If

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Dest
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mail").Range("A2").Value
            .CC = ""
            .Subject = "Back Order Update"
            .Body = "Thank you for joining the back order trial we are currently running. at the moment this is only a trial and this wont be reflective of the end product what we are looking to get right is the data(Attached) and how it is presented to you the opticians. please if you could send your review of the attached spreadsheet and any changes you would like to be made to JBradfield@coopervision.co.uk. Thank you for your participation "
            .Attachments.Add Dest.FullName
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Send   'or use .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub`
```

I was wondering if anyone can please help with this.

many thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 0):

change the pivot table filter in “result” sheet. Check this code, it might help you

```
    Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("E5")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
 Set pt = Worksheets("Results").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
 pt.PivotFields("User Name").ClearAllFilters
 pt.PivotFields("User Name").CurrentPage = Range("E5").Value
    End If
 End Sub

Sub Mail()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim Mess As Object, Recip As String, Subj As String
    Dim pt As Range
    Set pt = Worksheets("Results").Range("K8:T21").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    Recip = [E5].Value & "@Email.com"
    Subj = [G15].Value
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Mess = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    With Mess
        .Subject = Subj
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(pt)
        .Recipients.Add Recip
        .cc = "abc@email.com"
                    ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".send" to
            ' send the e-mail message.
        .display
    End With
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Sanya For Coming back to me. I really Appreciated your help. How do you mean change the "pivot table filter in “result” sheet" Sorry I am really new to this